# Get URL path for image from episerver blob file

Tags: content-management-system, episerver, optimizely

I'm creating a blob file using the following method in my code

**Adding to Blob**

```
 Thumbnail = MediaToBlob(thumbMediaUrl, accessToken, ".jpg", blobFactory, qbankMedia, "text/html");
                                    blobCache.Add(videoMediaUrl, qbankMedia.BinaryData);
```

**MediaToBlob Method**

```
public Blob MediaToBlob(string mediaUrl, string accessToken, string extension, IBlobFactory blobFactory, IQBankEpiMedia qbankMedia, string mimeType, int maxLength = int.MaxValue)
        {
            var mediaStream = GetMediaStream(mediaUrl, accessToken, mimeType, maxLength);

            Blob blob = null;

            if (mediaStream != null)
            {
                blob = blobFactory.CreateBlob(qbankMedia.BinaryDataContainer, extension);

                using (var blobStream = blob.OpenWrite())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = mediaStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        blobStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    mediaStream.Flush();
                    mediaStream.Close();
                }
            }

            return blob;
        }
```

I Need to get a relative path to this Thumbnail object so that I can use it to render the image in site. I can use Thumbnail.ID.AbsoluteUri to get this :

```
epi.fx.blob://default/f791355aa6334c92b5f370c5cfafd971/adc882777a04431baae83a2e05f3f02d.jpg
```

instead of that, i need something like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/episerver/f791355aa6334c92b5f370c5cfafd971/adc882777a04431baae83a2e05f3f02d.jpg
```

Can anyone guide me to have something that I can use as normal Url for images?

Comment: Are you looking to render a thumbnail on the actual site? If so, you probably want to look into some other solution for cropping/scaling images. The Thumbnail part is primarily intended for the CMS user interface - not the public-facing website.

Answer (score 2):

You can access thumbnail properties by appending the property name to the URL:

```cs
private readonly IUrlResolver _urlResolver;

var thumbnailUrl = _urlResolver.GetUrl(imageContentReference) + "/thumbnail";
```

This works for any thumbnail property your content type might have. 'Thumbnail' is the default propety available on ImageData.

Answer (score 0):

When you load an image or a media file into Episerver, it will be treated as content, it will have a content reference and consequently, you will also be able to get assets using it. So when saving a file to the blob you should then use that to save the media content. You can then get the url like you do to any content in episerver.

I would recomend checking these two blog post by Jon

[How to upload an image into episerver cms via code](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-episerver-cms/episerver-developers-tutorials/images-files-assets-and-media-within-episerver/how-to-upload-an-image-into-episerver-cms-via-code/)

[How to get the url for an image in episerver](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-episerver-cms/episerver-developers-tutorials/images-files-assets-and-media-within-episerver/how-to-get-the-url-for-an-image-in-episerver/)